# Cannot create post my values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to use create, but when I post my values don´t register in my database also in my view too.

Model:

```
public class WebPages
{
    [Key]
    public DateTime DomainStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime DomainExp { get; set; }



}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class WebPagesViewModel
{

    public DateTime DomainStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime DomainExp { get; set; }

}
```

Post Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult>Create([Bind(Include = "DomainName,DomainExp")] WebPagesViewModel model)
{

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            model.WC();
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "WebPages");
        }


    return View(model);
}
```

Extension method of my post:

```
public static WebPagesViewModel WC(this WebPagesViewModel model)
{
    var wb= new WebPages
    {
        DomainStart = model.DomainStart,
        DomainExp = model.DomainExp,
    };
    db.WebPagesList.Add(wb);
    db.SaveChangesAsync();  
    return model;
}
```

So try catch pass, and I get a success post, but values don´t save on database, what I´m doing wrong?
Thankyou in advance!

Comment: You forgot using `[HttpPost]`

Comment: Did you step through the code in the debugger? The current implementation of the `catch` block calls the `Danger` method, but the flow continues to `return View(model);`. So depending on the `Danger` method you might not see anything on the client that an exception has happened.

Comment: Sorry I have it, buy I dont include in post,I update now

Comment: My danger method Its only an alerts I create,if I delete it and my try catch Its the same result

Comment: use savechange not savechangeasync in webpagecreate.

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint in the Post method? As the implementation stands now, you might miss exceptions that are thrown in the code. You could also remove the `try-catch` for testing purposes so that you do not suppress exceptions.

Comment: if I change my async method, I get an error in dropdown of my view "the view data ítem has a key selected client  is of type system.int32 but must be of type ienumerable <selectlistitem>

Comment: async will always run bag ound so it should not show baground error@Demain

Comment: @MidhunMundayadan  
I delete my async and I found an error on dropdown of my View "the view data ítem has a key selected client is of type system.int32 but must be of type ienumerable <selectlistitem>", I update my view now

Comment: what is `WebPagesCreate`

Comment: @anand its an extension method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult>.      Create([Bind(Include = "DomainName,DomainExp,DomainEmails,DomainUsers,DomainPasswords,ClientsName")]
```

Change your post method to

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "DomainName,DomainExp,DomainEmails,DomainUsers,DomainPasswords,ClientsName")]
```

//model.WebPagesCreate(); 
pass parameter to the above method

if you want to see error

```
db.SaveChangesAsync()
```

change to

```
db.SaveChanges()
```

And also check bind values are correctly coming from the view
Add this to view model

```
public WebPagesViewModel()
{
    AvalilableClients = new List<SelectListItem>();   
}
public List<SelectListItem> AvalilableClients { get; set; }
```

Add your client list to Model

```
 foreach (var client in Clients )
 {
        model.WebPagesViewModel.Clients .Add(item: new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = dept.DepartmentName,
            Value = dept.DepartmentId.ToString()
        });
    }
```

Then Pass model to View Then populate the view drop down using Html Healper

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedClient, Model.AvalilableClients , new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: are you forget to add `model` to `WebPages`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solve it, the problem was that my datetime is not setted correctly in my extension method, so I change `DomainStart = model.DomainStart` to `DomainStart = Datetime.now`